# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key /tcb/posterloc/below right

Tags: positioning, posters

Box B located below right=1cm and 2cm of BOXA.

But: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key /tcb/posterloc/below right

How can i fix it?

Thanks

My minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%%%A
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {
columns=1,
rows=2,
spacing=3mm,
height=14cm,
width=6cm,
},
]
\posterbox[
colframe = red,
width=5cm, height= 4cm
]{name=BOXA,column=1}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\vspace{2cm}
\posterbox[
colframe = blue,
width=5cm, height= 5cm
]{below right=1cm and 2cm of TCBPOSTER@BOXA}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`below right=1cm and 2cm of ...` is a node placement specification for the Ti*k*Z `positioning` library, but isn't listed in the valid *placement* options for `\posterbox`. I suppose what you want to achieve is the following, using `xshift=1cm` and `yshift=-2cm`. See *Library poster* → *Box Placement* in the [tcolorbox manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for the list and descriptions of all valid *placement* options for `\posterbox`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[poster = {columns=1, rows=2, spacing=3mm, height=14cm,
                            width=6cm}]
\posterbox[colframe = red, width=5cm, height= 4cm]
  {name=BOXA,column=1}
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}

\posterbox[colframe = blue, width=5cm, height= 5cm]
  {column=1, row=1, xshift=1cm, yshift=-2cm}
  {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. No other solution for placement of Box B related with Box A?

Comment: I indicated where the placement options are listed in the `tcolorbox` manual, did you read the section I pointed you to (*Library poster* → *Box Placement*)? This is in pages 415-420 in my version of the manual.